# CSV writer writes the whole list in one Column (error?)

Tags: python, csv

I am currently trying to write a nested list into an excel file

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...]
```

I am using the standard method I have found on countless websites:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerows(data)
```

This is supposed to give me an output in excel like:

A|B|C

1 2 3

4 5 6

But my output is always the whole List in the first Column:

A

1,2,3

4,5,6

Even if I copy an exact example that uses wr.writerows(data) and on the website it says that each data should be in their own column on a single row, when i open it in excel its all in the first column. For any advice I would be very thankful

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. Forget excel, tell us the **actual text that is produced**, what is in the `out.csv` file?

Comment: but it sounds like whatever delimiter excel is expecting is not the delimiter in your file. I suspect this is not a programming question, really, but rather, how to correctly open the file in excel.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are absolutely correct. If I use "data = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')" and open it in excel, he formats it correctly. it was not an issue of my script but Excel expecting a different delimiter to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution after a hint from the comments.
The above code works correctly, but my excel programm expected ";" as a delimiter instead of "," thus it saw each list as one element and put it in one column instead of separating the data when opening the file. The following line fixes it:

```
data = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
```